# How can I find out my current mail server for Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, php, mail-server

I am very new to linux and I set this up a while ago. I am now having problems sending mail to uncommon domains. For example my PHP scripts will send emails to yahoo, gmail, etc. etc. without problem. But if it is an uncommon domain such as blah.com it does not send. So I figured my first step in trying to fix this would be figuring out my mail server :D any other suggestions are welcome.

I searched over google but have came up empty and its about time I tried this site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get an error message or do you get an e-mail back which would indicate why your mail could be send?

Answer (score 5):

You can see which packages are installed on your system using the `dpkg -l` command. If you combine it with the `grep` tool to search for specific words (e.g. `mail`) you can find out which packages with `mail` in their name are installed. Look for lines that start with `i` (for "installed"). For example:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep mail
ii  bsd-mailx       8.1.2-0.20131005cvs-1       amd64        simple mail user agent
ii  libmail-sml     0.79.16-1                   all          Send email from a perl script
ii  libphp-phi      5.1-1                       all          full featured email transfer class for PHP
ii  lockfile-g      0.1.17                      amd64        Programs for locking and unlocking files and mailboxes
ii  mime-supp       3.54ubuntu1                 all          MIME files 'mime.types' & 'mailcap', and support programs
ii  postfix         2.11.0-1                    amd64        High-performance mail transport agent
```

shows that I have the PostFix mail server installed. Other options are, for example, Exim and SendMail.